# Is this aggregation possible in the Mule ESB DataMapper

Tags: dictionary, mule, esb

Is this aggregation possible in the Mule ESB DataMapper

I have the following structures:

Strcuture A:

```
<item>
  <id>123</id>
  <price>1</price>
</item>
<item>
  <id>124</id>
  <price>2</price>
</item>
<item>
  <id>125</id>
  <price>3</price>
</item>
```

Structure B:

```
<total>
  <totalPrice>6</totalPrice>
</total>
```

If I want a sumation of all the  fields
in structure A to be placed into the totalprice 
of structure B, would taht be possible in the DataMapper.

If it is possible, how would you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source XML you show is invalid, you can only have one root element to have a valid XML. So  I guess you have a `<items>` root element.

You could say, from prices generate total, and then create an xpath rule with `sum(//price)` and then map it to total.